# Error in my admin: System > tools > support > system backups

Tags: admin-panel, backup

Unable to create backup due to missing required bash tools: lsof

What does this mean and how do i fix it?

I've just migrated from AWS where I was using Apache to RackSpace and now I'm using NginX. That's the only difference between my builds for the most part. I migrated all the files and the DB over. Additionally, I deleted all instances of the redis module.

I read that you could yum lsof in ssh and i tried it, it seemed to enable. I'm still throwing the error in my admin panel.